# Returning consecutive positive number sequences in a list

Tags: python, list, jython

I need to return the longest sequence of positive numbers in a list. 
currently I have:

```
def longestSequencePos(nums):
    longest_sequence = []
    current_sequence = []

    for obj in nums:
        if current_sequence and current_sequence[-1]+1 == obj:
            current_sequence.append(obj)
        else:
            current_sequence = [obj]
        if len(current_sequence) > len(longest_sequence):
            longest_sequence = current_sequence
    return sum(1 for obj in longest_sequence if obj > 0)
```

This only returns the total number of positive numbers which appear consequentially, so it doesn't work when a sequence is something like 5, 8, 12. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [maximum subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) problem.

Answer (score 1):

In python you could:

```
def find_longest_sequence(source_list):
    longest_sequence = []
    current_sequence = []

    for obj in source_list:
            if current_sequence and current_sequence[-1]+1 == obj:
                current_sequence.append(obj)
            else:
                current_sequence = [obj]
            if len(current_sequence) > len(longest_sequence):
                longest_sequence = current_sequence
    return longest_sequence
print "Longest sequence:", find_longest_sequence([1,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7])
```

Comment: actually, all I have to do is return the number of integers in the sequence. not the sequence itself.